# Highcharts not allowing any other content in body

Tags: html, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart on a page. If I try to add ANYTHING to the body, it does not show up on the page. It seems like Highcharts is blocking everything from appearing. Does anyone else have this problem or know how to resolve it?

EDIT: ok jsfiddle link in comment below.
It's not working as I've pasted the highshcarts.js and export.js file as I can't reference them externally. So if someone could adjust it slightly so it does actually work then that would be great.

So from this, it is not allowing me to add any extra content in the body or header for that matter.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you provide some code.

Comment: Please provide some code and best is fiddle(jsfiddle.net) as code paste misses dependencies some times..

Comment: How do I reference an external js file in jsfiddle? It is a highchart.js but I do not have a URL for it, just a local file.

Comment: I've been working with Highcharts, both on pure JS and with the .NET library. No problems whatsoever. Please show us some code for a start.

Comment: My comment is above yours, how do I reference an external js file? Since I don't have a URL for it, just a local file.

Comment: Please recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net

Comment: Again for the third time, how do you reference an external js file in jsfiddle? I can't recreate anything anywhere until I know how to reference that external file...

Comment: If you can't reference an external file in jsFiddle, you can just copy the contents of that file into the jsFiddle. Certainly not ideal or production ready but sometimes you need to think out side the box a little to get things done.

Comment: jsfiddle link here: like I said above it's not working. I'm not a javascript genius so I don't know why. http://jsfiddle.net/7NCcN/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the Highchart code in like you did. Your best bet for creating a fiddle for Highchart is to start with one from the demo site that closely resembles what you want. And then customize from there.

Here is a working fiddle. jsfiddle.net/7NCcN/2/
I added some text before and after the container div to show you that other content on the page will render.

See this fiddle to see what a standalone page's source code would look like: fiddle.jshell.net/7NCcN/2/show/

EDIT: Sorry for the non-link links. It is needed to get around the lame requirement that jsFiddle links also include a code block.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Did you change anything in the jsfiddle? I am using Rapidweaver and I used the exact same code as you used and it doesn't appear. I also have an absolute image that appears then once the highchart loads it dissapears. THoughts?

Comment: I didn't change anything in your chart options. All I did was cut out the Highchart source files and include them in the HTML section. And selected the jQuery library to be included. That got it working. Then added the text before and after. Your chart was not modified. Clearly there is nothing wrong with the chart code since it renders in the jsFiddle. You might need to paste the entire finished page source here or link to it if possible.